# Play the video in Landscape mode iOS 7

Tags: ios, video, landscape

In my application, I'm trying to play video using URL from my server . I'm using the `UITableView` to display the video list and by tapping the Cell from the list, the video will play in sub view. Now I want to play the video in landscape mode.

This is the current video code.

```
    _movieplayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]initWithContentURL: [NSURL URLWithString:[self urlencode:self.strPlayUrl]]];
    [[_movieplayer view] setFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height)];
    [self.view addSubview: [_movieplayer view]];
    [_movieplayer setShouldAutoplay:YES];
    [_movieplayer prepareToPlay];

    [self.movieplayer play];
```

In the above code, how do I make it work so that it plays in landscape mode. Please guide me on this. Been stuck on this for a long time.

Comment: nice question. also had the same problem. did you get your solution?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your viewcontroller with the movieplayer

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) MPMoviePlayerController* mpc;

- (void)setUpMPC
{
    NSURL* m = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"YourVideo" withExtension:@"mp4"];
    MPMoviePlayerController* mp = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:m];
    self.mpc = mp; // retain policy
    self.mpc.shouldAutoplay = NO;
    [self.mpc prepareToPlay];
    self.mpc.view.frame = CGRectMake(50, 50, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height);
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
    }
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}
```

Comment: Does your app allow the landscape orientation?

Comment: Under General->deployment info -> tick landscape orientations

Comment: ya it will allow the landscape orientation is checked

Comment: please tell wt i have to do now

Comment: i changed the solution, i think it has something to do with you adding the movie as a subview. The new solution shows you how to add the movieplayer.

Comment: @nvchopra the video is coming in small size is not playing in landscape mode

Comment: Yes that is because of the dimensions specified. You can use self.mpc.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen; to change to full screen

Comment: I did one more edit for you, this really should work, try it out on a new project. Make sure orientations are allowed.

Comment: All you have to do is play the video in fullscreen mode and then use UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape to keep the orientation in landscape mode. There really isnt much to it.

Comment: please tell me where i have to add the orientation code

Comment: The orientation code has to be placed in the viewcontroller.m file where the video lives

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should implement the `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` and `supportedInterfaceOrientations` methods in your viewController

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) MPMoviePlayerController*  moviePlayerController;

#pragma mark # - Init -

- (void) createAndPlayMovieForURL: (NSURL*) movieURL
{
    self.moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL: movieURL];
    [self.moviePlayerController.view setFrame: self.view.bounds];

    [self.view addSubview: self.moviePlayerController.view];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront: self.overlayView];
}

#pragma mark - Rotation -

- (BOOL) shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: (UIInterfaceOrientation) interfaceOrientation
{ 
    return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger) supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
}
```

Comment: have you checked that `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` and `supportedInterfaceOrientations` ever called?

Comment: tell me how to call that

Comment: [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/supportedInterfaceOrientations) `supportedInterfaceOrientations. When the user changes the device orientation, the system calls this method on the root view controller or the topmost presented view controller that fills the window. If the view controller supports the new orientation, the window and view controller are rotated to the new orientation. Is only called if the view controller’s shouldAutorotate method returns YES.`